# Android Studio - Bitmap Lose Quality When Taking Image from Camera

Tags: android, image, mobile, bitmap, camera

I need get the image from Camera to transform it in a Hash to send to provider in a JSON.

However, when I take image from camera, the Bitmap lose quality. After taking image, in the result screen the image has the correct quality, but, after I retrieve the Bitmap from the data of the result callback, the image lose quality:

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

launcherForCamera.launch(camera);


launcherForCamera = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() 
{
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result)
    {
        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Bitmap image = (Bitmap) result.getData().getExtras().get("data");

            if (image != null)
            {
                File directoryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/Test/Images/");

                if (!directoryPath.exists())
                {
                    directoryPath.mkdir();
                }

                File file = new File(directoryPath, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                try
                {

                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Picture saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    outputStream.close();
                }

                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I tried to change JPEG compress format to PNG and nothing. I won't save the image, only get it to transform in a hash.

Comment: Why do you think it loses quality?  How are you using it/displaying it that makes you think so?  Because a PNG image is 100% quality, no data is lost.  A JPG can lose quality when compressed, a PNG never will.  (Your current code uses JPG)

Comment: The `data` Bitmap you get back is a thumbnail size image. Were you expecting a full size image back?

Comment: @GabeSechan I was getting the thumbnail, it was the problem!

Comment: @ianhanniballake yeah! I was expecting! But I didn't know about the thumbnail

Comment: Thanks guys! The problem was that I was getting thumbnail than image full size! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing might be related to how the image data is returned from the camera intent. In the code you've provided, you're retrieving the thumbnail image data using the key "data". This thumbnail is usually a lower-resolution version of the captured image.

To get the full-resolution image, you should instead save it to a file specified by you (which you're doing), and then use that file's path to manipulate or process the image. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
launcherForCamera.launch(camera);

launcherForCamera = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
    if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = result.getData().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.get("data") != null) {
            // Thumbnail image (lower resolution)
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            // Use the file you've saved
            File directoryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/Test/Images/");
            if (!directoryPath.exists()) {
                directoryPath.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(directoryPath, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Thumbnail picture saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                outputStream.close();

                // Process the full-resolution image from the file path
                // You can use 'file' here to process the full image or create a hash
                // Example: convertFileToHash(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In this code, thumbnail is the lower-resolution image captured by the camera, while the file variable holds the path to the high-resolution image. You should use the file to perform further processing, such as creating a hash, rather than using the thumbnail.

Comment: Your code is not what I needed. But, your explanation solved my problem! The problem is I was getting the thumbnail than image full size. Thanks! You help me a lot!